# Java: Generic method overloading ambiguity

Tags: java, generics, overloading, variadic-functions

Consider the following code:

```
public class Converter {

    public <K> MyContainer<K> pack(K key, String[] values) {
        return new MyContainer<>(key);
    }

    public MyContainer<IntWrapper> pack(int key, String[] values) {
        return new MyContainer<>(new IntWrapper(key));
    }


    public static final class MyContainer<T> {
        public MyContainer(T object) { }
    }

    public static final class IntWrapper {
        public IntWrapper(int i) { }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        MyContainer<IntWrapper> test = converter.pack(1, new String[]{"Test", "Test2"});
    }
}
```

The above code compiles without problems. However, if one changes `String[]` to `String...` in both `pack` signatures and `new String[]{"Test", "Test2"}` to `"Test", "Test2"`, the compiler complains about the call to `converter.pack` being ambiguous.

Now, I can understand why it could be considered ambiguous (as `int` can be autoboxed into an `Integer`, thus matching the conditions, or lack thereof, of `K`). However, what I can't understand is why the ambiguity isn't there if you're using `String[]` instead of `String...`.

Can someone please explain this odd behavior?

Comment: There have been similar questions before, but I'll admit they are a bit special, hard to find. Still makes one think nontheless! : S

Comment: This syntactic sugar tickles you every now and while and all you can do is read JLS and wait for an answer!

Comment: Syntactic sugar or not, I would still expect it to behave consistently with the rest of the language.

Comment: This is really a nice question. Very hard to get the actual answer.

Comment: The most surprising behaviour is the 1st method is not at all applicable for that method invocation, as `1` cannot be converted to `IntWrapper` by method invocation conversion. This is really eating my head now. Still roaming around JLS.

Comment: Just my guess... I think the reason is that `String...` is a "fallback" of some sort, the same way that type-inference is a fallback. It's a "secondary" match (i.e. there isn't an exact match), and since there are two secondary matches, the compiler doesn't know what to do. This is not a rigorous explanation by any means though, +1 great question.

Comment: @RohitJain `1` is never converted to `IntWrapper`. The assigment to `test` and its type is irrelevant for selecting the right method. It could very well be the generic one and return `MyContainer<Integer>`. This could not be assigned to `test` but as I said this is not regarded.

Comment: One thing is we should not generally overload var args method. The compiler may really be getting ultra confused. When we use String[] instead of String ..., there is no var args method, so may be you are not facing any issue. But still, am trying to figure out the reason for the compilation error ;)

Comment: @stonedsquirrel. Umm. It seems like you are right. And that comes as  a surprise to me. I would expect the compiler to infer the type of `K` from the method invocation context. So, `K` should be inferred as `IntWrapper`, as clear from the assignment.

Comment: @RohitJain It can't. The type argument has to be a specific type. As polymorphism is possible in assignments the type of the variable might not be the intended generic type. Consider a method `T foo(T arg)` that is called this way: `Type myVar = foo(new Subtype());`. This would result in a conflict when determining the generic type from both the actual parameter and the assignment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your 1<sup>st</sup> case is pretty straight-forward. The below method:

```
public MyContainer<IntWrapper> pack(int key, Object[] values)
```

is an exact match for arguments - `(1, String[])`. From [JLS Section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion

Now, there is no boxing involved while passing those parameters to the 2nd method. As `Object[]` is a super type of `String[]`. And passing `String[]` argument for `Object[]` parameter was a valid invocation even before Java 5.

---

### Compiler seems to play trick in your 2nd case:

In your 2nd case, since you have used var-args, the method overloading resolution will be done using both var-args, and boxing or unboxing, as per the 3rd phase explained in that JLS section:

> The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

Note, the 2nd phase is not applicable here, due to the use of *var-args*:

> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation.

<strike>Now what is happening here is *compiler* is not inferring the type argument correctly*</strike> (Actually, it's inferring it correctly as the type parameter is used as formal parameter, see the update towards the end of this answer). So, for your method invocation:

```
MyContainer<IntWrapper> test = converter.pack(1, "Test", "Test2");
```

compiler should have inferred the type of `K` in generic method to be `IntWrapper`, from the LHS. But it seems like it is inferring `K` to be an `Integer` type, due to which both your methods are now equally applicable for this method call, as both of the requires `var-args` or `boxing`.

However, if the result of that method is not assigned to some reference, then I can understand that compiler cannot infer proper type as in this case, where is is perfectly acceptable to give an ambiguity error:

```
converter.pack(1, "Test", "Test2");
```

May be I guess, just to maintain consistency, it is also marked ambiguous for the first case. But, again I'm not really sure, as I haven't found any credible source from JLS, or other official reference which talks about this issue. I'll keep on searching, and if I get to find one, will update the answer.

---

### Let's trick the compiler by explicit type information:

If you change the method invocation to give explicit type information:

```
MyContainer<IntWrapper> test = converter.<IntWrapper>pack(1, "Test", "Test2");
```

Now, the type `K` will be inferred as `IntWrapper`, but since `1` is not convertible to `IntWrapper`, that method is discarded, and 2nd method will be invoke and it will work perfectly fine.

---

Frankly speaking, I really don't know what is happening here. I would expect the compiler to infer the type parameter from the method invocation context in the first case also, as it works for following problem:

```
public static <T> HashSet<T> create(int size) {  
    return new HashSet<T>(size);  
}
// Type inferred as `Integer`, from LHS.
HashSet<Integer> hi = create(10);
```

But, it is not doing in this case. So this can possibly be a bug.

*Or may be I don't understand exactly how the Compiler infers the type arguments, when the type is not passed as an argument. So, for learning more about this, I tried going through - [JLS §15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) and [JLS §15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8), which is about how compiler infers the type argument, but that is going completely over the very top of my head.

So, for now you have to live with it, and use the alternative (providing explicit type argument).

---

### It turns out, Compiler wasn't playing any trick:

As finally explained in comment by @zhong.j.yu., compiler only applies section 15.12.2.8 for type inference, when it fails to infer it as per 15.12.2.7 section. But here, it can infer the type as `Integer` from the argument being passed, as clearly the type parameter is a format parameter in the method.

So, yes compiler correctly infers the type as `Integer`, and hence the ambiguity is valid. And now I think this answer is complete.

Comment: Why is it that the first phase(15.12.2.2) is not able to resolve when var args is used. What I see is that without boxing, it could have identified the right signature.

Comment: OK, brings some more light. Nevertheless I disagree that the compiler can or even should deduct the method to call from the LHS (your 2nd paragraph). In my answer I am calling the methods and simply ignore the result.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname. Yeah that point is correct that the compiler cannot infer the type when the result is not assigned to LHS, but it should in this case. May be for consistency purpose this invocation is marked ambiguous.

Comment: @ShivaKumar. If you read that JLS Section, you will get to know that the var-args is the last thing which is considered.

Comment: So this seems to be a design descision. Nice work. You should add that the second phase is "allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation". Think it would be possible to add a phase between current 2 and 3 that analyzes variable arity method invocation but ignores boxing. They just didn't do it.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel. I guess they didn't have that case because boxing is prefered over var-args AFAIK. And will add that 2nd phase. Thanks :)

Comment: 15.12.2.8 is only applied for type arguments not inferred from 15.12.2.7. in this case, K is already inferred as Integer from the method argument `1`, so the assignment context is not used for inference.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu. Derp. Totally missed that. Thank you for taking your time out going through those sections. :)

Comment: @zhong.j.yu Added your explanation to the answer, just to make it complete.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, the difference between the below two methods:
Method 1:

```
   public MyContainer<IntWrapper> pack(int key, Object[] values) {
    return new MyContainer<>(new IntWrapper(""));
   }
```

Method 2:

```
public MyContainer<IntWrapper> pack(int key, Object ... values) {
    return new MyContainer<>(new IntWrapper(""));
}
```

Method 2 is as good as

```
public MyContainer<IntWrapper> pack(Object ... values) {
    return new MyContainer<>(new IntWrapper(""));
 }
```

That is why you get an ambiguity..

**EDIT**
Yes I want to say that they are the same for the compile. The whole purpose of using variable arguments is to enable a user to define a method when he/she is not sure about the 
number of arguments of a given type.

So if you are using an object as variable arguments, you just say the compiler that I am not sure how many objects I will send and on the other hand, you are saying,"I am passing an integer and unknown number of objects". For the compiler the integer is an object as well.

If you want to check the validity try passing an integer as the first argument and then pass a variable argument of String. You will see the difference.

For e.g.:

```
public class Converter {
public static void a(int x, String... y) {
}

public static void a(String... y) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    a(1, "2", "3");
}
}
```

Also, please do not use the arrays and variable args interchangeably, they have some different purposes altogether.

When you use varargs the method doesn't expect an array but different parameters of the same type, which can be accessed in an indexed manner.

Comment: Uhh... am I the only one not following?

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler treats ´int, Object..." and "Object..." as equivalent? If that is actually true, it sounds completely absurd to me.

Comment: @GGrec: I will second that motion I don't get it.

Comment: It IS absurd. `int, Object...` tells us that there must be at least ONE `int` parameter, while `Object...` can be none or more of type `Object`.

Comment: Actually, after making a quick test, this does actually seem to be the case: `public static void a(int x, Object... y) { } public static void a(Object... y) { } public static void main(String[] args) { a(1, "", ""); }`

Comment: @Smallhacker Isn't this irrelevant to your question?

Comment: @GGrec I have yet to determine that for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to my real-world scenario. It may however be relevant to the simplified problem I asked. I'm going to update my example a bit to see if this is still the case.

Comment: How is this possible, the primitive int has nothing to do with an Obejct type. : S Unless of course the compiler is prepared for autoboxing in which case essentially you would be able to call the method with the wrapper class Integer. That would be truly ambigouos.

Comment: @dharam. Your reasoning is not at all answering the question. There you go, just remove the first method (generic method), and you see that the method invocation is fine. Why is it?

Comment: @dharam While you indeed seem to be correct about this, the ambiguity does disappear when you use a `String...` parameter. I've now updated the question to use strings instead of objects. (The use of `Object` is an artifact of me oversimplifying the real-world scenario.) Is your explanation still accurate in this case too?

Comment: @Smallhacker...My argument is valid for all scenarios where there are multiple methods where one method is accepting two parameters of the same type( the second parameter being a vararg)

And eeh second method accepts only varargs of the same type. 

In my edit I have also mentioned that it is not similar to passing an array of a given type. It is like passing n separate parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In this case

```
(1) m(K,   String[])
(2) m(int, String[])

m(1, new String[]{..});
```

m(1) satisfies [15.12.2.3. Phase 2: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3)

m(2) satisfies [15.12.2.2. Phase 1: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)

Compiler stops at Phase 1; it found m(2) as the only applicable method at that phase, therefore m(2) is chosen.

In the var arg case

```
(3) m(K,   String...)
(4) m(int, String...)

m(1, str1, str2);
```

Both m(3) and m(4) satisfy [15.12.2.4. Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4) . Neither is more specific than the other, therefore the ambiguity.

We can group applicable methods into 4 groups:

1. applicable by subtyping
2. applicable by method invocation conversion
3. vararg, applicable by subtyping
4. vararg, applicable by method invocation conversion

The spec merged group 3 and 4 and treat them both in Phase 3. Therefore the inconsistency.

Why did they do that? Maye they just got tired of it.

Another critique would be that, there shouldn't be all these phases, because programmers don't think in that way. We should simply find all applicable methods indiscriminately, then choose the most specific one (with some mechanism to avoid boxing/unboxing)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is only some first clues... may edit for more.

The compiler always searches and selects the most specific method available. Though a bit clumsy to read, it's all specified in [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Thus, by calling

> converter.pack(1,  "Test", "Test2" )

it's not determinable for the compiler whether the `1` shall be dissolved to `K` or `int`. In other words, K can apply to any type, so it's at the same level as int/Integer.

The difference lies in the number and type of the arguments. Consider that `new String[]{"Test", "Test2"}` is an array, while `"Test", "Test2"` are two arguments of type String!

> converter.pack(1); // ambiguous, compiler error
>
> converter.pack(1, null); // calls method 2, compiler warning
>
> converter.pack(1, new String[]{}); // calls method 2, compiler warning
>
> converter.pack(1, new Object());// ambiguous, compiler error
>
> converter.pack(1, new Object[]{});// calls method 2, no warning